# I'm trying to set the state with new filtered data but form stops filtering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filter

I'm trying to set new filtered data in a state **(setFilteredCategories)** so I could send it to another component but somehow it does not work. While when I log them, the data come as intended.

```
const handleSearchCategory = (value: any) => {
    const filteredCat = categories?.payload.filter((entry: { [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>) =>
      Object.values(entry).some(val => typeof val === "string" && val.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
    setFilteredCategories(filteredCat)
    console.log(filteredCat);
  }
```

Comment: You will have to tell use where/how you use the method. And how/where you use the `filteredCategories` data after the update.

Comment: The thing is I haven't even used it yet. I just set it whether I used it or not, the outcome is the same. 
Note handleSearchCategory is onchange function.

Comment: This is my input

`<Input type="text" name="searchCategory"
 placeholder="Search category"
 onChange={handleSearchCategory}
 suffixIcon={
 <Image
 width={14}
 src="/icons/ic-actions-search-DESKTOP-JLD6GCT.svg" preview={false} alt=""
 /> } />`

This is my state

`const [filteredCategories, setFilteredCategories] = useState("")`